# Error when loading cross compiled kernel module

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel, cross-compiling

I have cross compiled a simple helloworld kernel module, the host is a x86 machine and the target an ARM board. When I do modprobe to install the module in the target i get this message:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

I have make sure that the module is compiled with the same version as the target.

```
uname -a : 3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty

modinfo: vermagic:       3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
```

What can be the problem? What does that error means?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it easier to read the code. Good luck!

Comment: `modprobe` **loads** (or **inserts**) module into kernel, it **does not install** module. What command you have used for *install* module to the target? Was it `cp` command, or `make ... modules_install`? BTW, `/lib/modules/3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty/modules.dep` should exist for load *any* module, not only one you have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are missing the file specifying module dependencies (generated at build time and installed with `make module_install`).

The simplest solution is, if your mdule does not have external dependencies, insert it with `insmod` rather than with `modprobe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
depmod -a
```

on the ARM board.

it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps.

1. Do **insmod $module-name**
2. Check the **dmesg** commands output. If you see the following message

> version magic '3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty xxxxxxxx' should be
>   '3.14.0-xilinx-13567-g906a2c9-dirty xxxxxxxxxx'

then the problem is because of the changes made to the kernel.

3. Commit the changes to the git repository and re-build the kernel.
4. Create a new kernel image and then boot the target with the updated kernel.